# How to create IOS style rubber scrollbar in unity?

Tags: unity, c#, scrolling

I'm looking to create a scroll bare similar to IOS scroll when you load page or something when it lets you pull all the way down but the tension gets higher like it is on spring. How would I approach this.

Answer (score 1):

The [ScrollRect](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-ScrollRect.html) component does this by default.

ScrollRect has a property called **MovementType**. If you set it to *Elastic*, you'll achieve the same effect you're looking for (the spring effect).

From the documentation:

> **Movement Type** Unrestricted, Elastic or Clamped. Use Elastic or Clamped to force the content to remain within the bounds of the Scroll Rect. Elastic mode bounces the content when it reaches the edge of the Scroll Rect

> **Elasticity**    This is the amount of bounce used in the elasticity mode.

Just right click in your hierarchy and go to UI->ScrollRect

[Here's a good video that goes more in detail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAqyi85IAJ0).

Comment: The problem with scrollRect is that it doesn't support multitouch.

Comment: Hmm...I see. Out of curiosity, why would you need a scrollbar to be multitouch compatible? I mean, usually you move the handle of the scroll bar with one finger

Comment: Well it doesn't need to be scrollbar it just needs that scroll functionality with elasticity. Basically to create game mechanic where you need  to pull the object to a threshold but the more you do the harder it gets so you need to use both fingers. Something like that, hope I explaned it well.

Comment: Hmm, alright, I see. So, right of the top of my head, I can think of the [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html) interface, which basically lets you, well, create draggable objects. You would have to manually implement the elasticity and the threshold. I can also think of tracking the touch count: one touch equals to x amount of force to pull the draggable object; the more touches you have, the more force you have.

Comment: Hm thanks I will try it out.